# Emailing the selected checkbox values

Tags: php, html

I've tried to research this but can't find anything that's working. I'm trying to get the values of the checkboxes selected to send through phpmailer

This is the html code for the form:

```
        <label for="pattern"><b>Working Patterns</b></label>
        <p>Please indicate the hours you would like/are able to work</p>

         <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="Full-Time Day">Full-Time Days
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="Full-Time Nights">Full-Time Nights
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="Part-Time am/pm">Part-Time  am/pm
        </label>
         <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="Temporary">Temporary
        </label>
         <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="hours[]" value="Student">Student
        </label>
```

And in my php code I've done:

```
if( isset($_POST['hours']) && is_array($_POST['hours']) ) {
    foreach($_POST['hours'] as $hours) {  
        echo "I have a {$hours}!";
    }
    $hoursList = implode(', ', $_POST['hours']);
}
```

This gets the selected values and will display them but when I do:

```
Work Pattern: {$_POST[$hoursList] }
```

in the email body I just get an error. For example if I select "Full-Time Days" and "Full-Time Nights" I just get the error: `Undefined index: Full-Time Day, Full-Time Nights in C:\xampp\htdocs\JG\application.php on line 49.`

The rest of the email will send it's just this bit I can't get right.

Really can't think of what I'm missing, I've spent ages trying to get this right and this is closest I've come, so any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference `$hoursList` not `$_POST[$hoursList]` in your work pattern.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry,  I'm new to doing this sort of thing

Comment: Wherever you build your email, all you should need to do is echo `$hoursList`. I assumed from the code you provided that you were trying to echo `$_POST[$hoursList]`

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you so much for your help, got it working :)